# Convert Query String URL to Path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to change `http://www.mywebsite.com/en/admin/index?page=archived`

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/admin/page/archived/
```

I've tried a bunch of things including:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+)$    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/admin/%1? [R=301,L]
```

but i have always a 404 error.

My .htaccess is into `admin directory`

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/admin/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/admin/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]   

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\?page=(.+?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index$ /en/admin/page/%1? [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ /en/admin/index?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Does the destination url you are trying to redirect to exist?

Comment: No, because i would like transform only the query string to a path url... It's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code in admin/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/admin/page/%1? [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ /en/admin/index?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you for your support, but I still `http://www.mywebsite.com/en/admin/index?page=archived` in my url browser

Comment: Is perfect !! Thanks very much for your support Starkeen !